# Printing a text file min and max value and is returning null

Tags: java, null

I just want to say before you read the rest of this i just want to figure out the issues why my output are printing these errors or null as i explain. If there is any other information you need please let me know thank you!

---

Hey guys so i'm trying to print out my text file and when i put in the case for which part of the file i want to print i print the max and min value and i'm getting this as my output. This goes for every variable for my inquiry it prints out the same thing.

```
Please input your rating file name
project 2.txt
Please pick inquiry: ratingPercentage, views, ratingScore, movieName, 
Release, exit
Release
The highest is null
null
The lowest is null
null
```

---

Here below are all of my files i am using to print my text file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> 
{
    String movieName;
    long ratingPercentage;
    int StudThatSeenMov;
    float averageRating;
    int movieReleaseYear;

    public Movie()
    {
        movieName = "";
        ratingPercentage = 0;
        StudThatSeenMov = 0;
        averageRating = 0;
        movieReleaseYear = 0;
    }
    public Movie(long ratingPer,int STSM,float averRate,String movName,int movReleaseYear)
    {
        movieName = movName;
        ratingPercentage = ratingPer;
        StudThatSeenMov = STSM;
        averageRating = averRate;
        movieReleaseYear = movReleaseYear;
    }
    public String getMovie()
    {
        return movieName;
    }
    public long getRate()
    {
        return ratingPercentage;
    }
    public int getViews()
    {
        return StudThatSeenMov;
    }
    public float getAverage()
    {
        return averageRating;
    }
    public int getMovieYear()
    {
        return movieReleaseYear;
    }
    public void setMovieName(String movName)
    {
        movieName = movName;
    }
    public void setRate(long ratingPer)
    {
        ratingPercentage = ratingPer;
    }
    public void setViews(int STSM)
    {
        StudThatSeenMov = STSM;
    }
    public void setAverage(float averRate)
    {
        averageRating = averRate;
    }
    public void setMovieRelease(int movReleaseYear)
    {
        movieReleaseYear = movReleaseYear;
    }
    @Override
        public int compareTo(Movie o) {
            return (this.movieName.compareTo(o.movieName));
        }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "" +averageRating + "\t" + StudThatSeenMov + "\t" + movieName + "\t"+ movieReleaseYear;
    }
}
    class MovRating implements Rating<Movie>
    {
        String ratingFile;
        ArrayList<Movie> movies = null;
        MovRating(String ratingFile)
        {
            this.ratingFile= ratingFile;
            movies = readInputFile();
        }
        ArrayList<Movie> getMovies()
        {
            return movies;
        }
        void setMovie(ArrayList<Movie> movies)
        {
            this.movies = movies;
        }
        private ArrayList<Movie> readInputFile()
        {
            ArrayList<Movie> lmovie = new ArrayList<>();
            if(this.ratingFile == null)
                return null;
            Scanner input;
            try{
                input = new Scanner(new File(this.ratingFile));
                while(input.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line = input.nextLine();
                    String[] elements = line.split("\t");
                    if(elements.length != 5) continue;
                    String tmp = (new StringBuilder(elements[0])).reverse().toString();
                    long ratingPercentage = Long.parseLong(tmp.trim(),10);
                    int StudThatSeenMov = Integer.parseInt(elements[1].trim());
                    float AverageRating = Float.parseFloat(elements[2].trim());
                    int movieReleaseYear = Integer.parseInt(elements[4].trim());
                    Movie m = new Movie(ratingPercentage,StudThatSeenMov,AverageRating,elements[3],movieReleaseYear);
                    lmovie.add(m);
                }
                input.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return(lmovie);
        }
        protected void produceOutput(ArrayList<Movie> movies, String query)
        {
            Comparator<Movie> cp = null;
            switch(query)
            {
            case"ratingPercentage":
            cp = new Comparator<Movie>()
            {
                public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2)
                {
                    return (int) (m2.ratingPercentage-m1.ratingPercentage);
                }
            };
            case"ratingScore":
                cp = new Comparator<Movie>()
                {
                    public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2)
                    {
                        return (int) (m2.averageRating-m1.averageRating);
                    }
                };
            break;
            case"Views":
                cp = new Comparator<Movie>()
                {
                    public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2)
                    {
                        return (int) (m2.StudThatSeenMov-m1.StudThatSeenMov);
                    }
                };
                break;
            case"movieName":
                cp = null;
                break;
            case"Release":
                cp = new Comparator<Movie>()
                {
                    public int compare(Movie m1,Movie m2)
                    {
                        return (int) (m2.movieReleaseYear - m1.movieReleaseYear);
                    }
                };
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Wrong output type");
                    return;
            }
            System.out.println(pickMax(cp));
            System.out.println(pickMin(cp));
        }
        @Override
        public Movie pickMax(Comparator<Movie> m)
        {
            MyPriorityQueue<Movie> pq = new MyPriorityQueue<>(movies,m);
            Movie m1 = pq.poll();
            System.out.println("The highest is " + m1);
            return m1;
        }
        @Override
        public Movie pickMin(Comparator<Movie> m)
        {
            if(m == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Reversing default comparable is not implemented");
                return pickMin(m);
            }else{
                Comparator<Movie> c = new Comparator<Movie>()
                {
                    public int compare(Movie m1,Movie m2)
                    {
                        return(c.compare(m2, m1));
                    }
                };
                MyPriorityQueue<Movie> pq = new MyPriorityQueue<>(movies,c);
                Movie m2 = pq.poll();
                System.out.println("The lowest is " + m2);
                return m2;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void add(Movie e)
        {
            movies.add(e);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            if((movies == null) || (movies.size() == 0))
            return true;
            else return false;
        }
        @Override
        public int size()
        {
            if((movies == null) || (movies.size() == 0))
            return 0;
            else return movies.size();
        }
    }
```

---

I am using this as the input text file to print

```
Project 2.txt file
0000022101 197 6.5 "Rampage" 2018
0000122101 24,139 6.0 "Pacific Rim Uprising" 2018
0000001221 78,114 7.9 "Ready Player One" 2018
0000122001 523 5.9 "Amateur" 2018
0000001212 223,659 7.8 "Black Panther" 2018
0000013200 138,664 7.0 "Jumanji:Welcome to the Jungle" 2017
0000012101 235,515 6.7 "Justice League" 2017
0000001221 484,477 7.8 "Captain America: Civil War" 2016
0000012101 528,313 6.6 "Batman v Superman:Dawn of Justice" 2016
0000001211 661,462 7.8 "Gravity" 2013
```

---

---

Printing output

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class QueryEngine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please input your rating file name");
        String ratingFile= new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        MovRating myRating = new MovRating(ratingFile);
        ArrayList<Movie> movies = myRating.getMovies();
        boolean moreQuery = true;
        while(moreQuery)
        {
            System.out.println("Please pick inquiry: ratingPercentage, " + "views, ratingScore, movieName, Release, exit" );
            String query = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            if(query.equals("exit")) moreQuery = false;
            else myRating.produceOutput(movies, query);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main method you are reading the file into a variable `movies` that you later send as a parameter to `produceOutput` but once in that method you don't use that parameter so when `pickMin` and `pickMax` are called later they are using the member `movies` which is null since it has never been assigned.

Add `movies` as a parameter to `pickMin` and `pickMax` or call `setMovie` (bad name btw) with the `movies` parameter in `produceOutput`.

Also learn how to use the debugger, it is a very helpful and powerful tool.